# MySQL Group_Concat still truncating results after group_concat_max_len is increased

Tags: mysql, truncate, group-concat

I'm dynamically pivoting a table in MySQL (well in php but 1 step at a time).

My concat looks like such:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(name = "', p.name,'",te.hours, 0)) AS  "', p.name, '"')) 
FROM time_entries te 
inner join projects p on p.id = te.project_id 
where te.spent_on >= '2016-07-01'; -- test date
```

My return is truncated quite early (some info redacted but same # of chars):

```
MAX(IF(name = "redact",te.hours, 0)) AS  "redact",MAX(IF(name = "red",te.hours, 0)) AS  "red",MAX(IF(name = "redactednamebutsamel",te.hours, 0)) AS  "redactednamebutsamel",MAX(IF(name = "red",te.hours, 0)) AS  "red",MAX(IF(name = "redactednamebutsameleng...
```

Now I know all about `max_allowed_packet` and `group_concat_max_len`, both are set to 16777216 on the server (found by running select queries on them, e.g Select @@max_allowed_packet;)

Here's the kicker, in the early phases of getting this right, I definitely returned the full string. But I can't at all reproduce the result.

Is there a glaring issue with my code? I am pretty new to MySQL and most of this was stitched together from google searches.

Thanks.

Edit: Issue must be elsewhere. I was able to view the full string and it seems everything is indeed there. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on how `group_concat_max_len` is set, the value may reset back to default on a server restart; could that be your issue?

Comment: Server has definitely not restarted since beginning this. 
Even if I include `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 102400` or `SET @@group_concat_max_len = 102400` I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: This was an operator error. Next question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tools / languages are you using?

It is quite usual for e.g. phpMyAdmin to show the text truncated in row view and only the full text when viewing a record.

Comment: This is all in MySQL workbench. This is just a snippet of my large query where is simply giving me syntax errors, I'm assuming because it is running into the truncation. Independently, my queries all work :S.

Comment: Syntax errors are structural errors in your query. They are never caused by truncation in the return of the data. In that case you would get some other error.

Comment: Right but the returned string is being concatenated again into a new query.

Is there someway that I can see the non-truncated results if that is the issue? Just for me to be able to put this to rest.

Comment: I found the view. you're right, my error is somewhere else. Thank you!